# How can i properly change the assigned secret key in a Django Web Application

Tags: python, django, secret-key

So, I'm trying to deploy a Django Web App to production, but I want to change the secret key before doing so.

I've attempted to generate a new key using a randomizing function and insert that new key in place of the old one. When I do so, I get an error that says the following:

> AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONEncoder' ...
>   Exception Location .../django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py in
>   , line 9

I've deleted the browser cache and restarted the server, but the error persists.
I've also attempted to change the key back, after deleting the browser cache and restarting, the error still persists.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Edit: Python version is 2.6.6 and Django version is 1.3.1

Comment: If you run `./manage.py check` what do you get? The same error?

Comment: Hmm what versions of python and django are you using? Looking at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py looks like something is broken with your `json` package...

Comment: I don't have the permissions to run ./manage.py check. Also, as far as the packages go, nothing has been changed in over a month. The only thing i did was change the secret key, the application threw the error on the UI, then i changed the key back and the error persisted.

Answer (score 8):

So, to answer my own question, changing the assigned key is done the same way you'd change any other variable. Just create a 50 character (ideally random) string and set SECRET_KEY equal to it.

SECRET_KEY = "#$%&N(ASFGAD^*(%326n26835625BEWSRTSER&^@T#%$Bwertb"

Then restart the web application.

My problem was completely unrelated. It occurred because I set the path python uses to locate packages to a weird location. Sorry about that guys.

Answer (score 5):

I like to use this pattern (where you would put your app's name instead of APP_NAME):

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
secret_key_env_variable_name = 'APP_NAME_SECRET_KEY'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get(secret_key_env_variable_name)
if len(SECRET_KEY) < 25:
    print( 'The value of $%s does not contain enough characters (%s characters)' % (secret_key_env_variable_name, len(SECRET_KEY)))
    raise RuntimeError('SECRET_KEY is not long enough (in environment variable "%s"' % secret_key_env_variable_name)
```

Then in the account that runs Django I export this variable in the .bashrc (use your applicable environment config file):

```
export APP_NAME_SECRET_KEY='oysmy1iv=n7ygq%og!b4@(k@40&5d-i&5%^c8$riw%3$r3yi(='
```

Note: that key was randomly generated with the first url for a generator after web searching for: generate a secret_key django.

Comment: Great answer, more complete than above. I would rate this as the answer if I was OP